# Font is not supported in Firefox

Tags: html, fonts

I used `font-face`, `font-family` etc, but Firefox is not supporting the font style, my font style is following, how to do it?

```
font-family:"TitilliumText22L Lt", Helvetica, SansSerif;
```

Comment: See the answers. Or, did you mean that Firefox displays this differently than another browser on the same machine? In that case, the answer will be different. (To do with user preferences, a missing dash etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Pay attention to the fact that browsers use your installed fonts to display the html page.

Because of that, your font (that is not a standard one I guess) would be available only on your pc and the rest of the world would see everything in "Helvetica".

You can consider insing **Google Font** to import the right font binary.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Most computers do not have Helvetica either, and probably no computer has SansSerif (this is a specific font name, as opposite to the CSS-defined generic font name sans-serif), so what most people would see is their browser’s default font for normal text.

Answer (score 1):

as for font issue. there is an issue for OS like XP and Window 7.

Example

window XP does not support **Calibri** while window 7 does. when you view it in does OS browser its different.

Try to choose a Font that will fit all OS and Browsers.
Check out google for the common used Font

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you used `font-face` correctly? I have personally used this and had success in Firefox.

Just in case, the syntax should look something like this:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: "TitilliumText22L Lt";
    src = url("/*Path to font file on your webserver*/")
}

body {
    font-family: "TitilliumText22L Lt", Helvetica, SansSerif;
}
```

Also, ensure that you are using a font file that is compatible with Firefox.